# Google appscript has suddenly stopped working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

It was working fine up until yesterday, its a script to take in one number and see how many combinations another set of numbers will add up to that one number. It is producing a blank field in column J, where it has been showing what combinations will make up the top number.

```
function findAndDisplayMaxCombination() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var targetAmount = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
    var values = sheet.getRange("G4:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();

    // Set the time limit to 3 minutes (in seconds)
    var timeLimit = 600;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the combination with the most values
    var maxCombination = findMaxCombination(targetAmount, values, startTime, timeLimit);

    // Ensure the script has permission to edit the sheet
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Authorization check passed. Updating the sheet...", "Status", 5);

    // Clear the contents of column I
    sheet.getRange("I4:I").clearContent();

    // Write each value in the max combination to column J
    for (var i = 0; i < maxCombination.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange("I" + (i + 4)).setValue(maxCombination[i]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Log any errors
    Logger.log("Error: " + error);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("An error occurred. Check the logs for details.", "Error", 5);
  }
}

function findMaxCombination(target, values, startTime, timeLimit) {
  var result = [];

  function search(index, currentSum, currentCombination) {
    // Check if the time limit has been exceeded
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > timeLimit * 1000) {
      return;
    }

    if (currentSum === target) {
      if (currentCombination.length > result.length) {
        result = currentCombination.slice(); // Update result with the longer combination
      }
      return;
    }

    if (index === values.length) {
      return;
    }

    search(index + 1, currentSum, currentCombination); // Exclude the current value
    search(index + 1, currentSum + values[index], currentCombination.concat(values[index])); // Include the current value
  }

  search(0, 0, []);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time for you to single step you way through the script to find out what's wrong.  Let us know what you learn about the problem while debugging it.

Comment: I've went over it for an hour now and have no idea what I'm missing. I didn't change anything between the time it was working and now.

Comment: timelimit is undefined inside of search

Comment: target is not defined  inside of search

Comment: startTime is undefined in search

Comment: I don't think it suddenly stopped working.  I don't think it ever worked.

Comment: It really did suddenly stop working. I was using this with no issue for a few weeks

Comment: There must have been some changes between the one that was working and the script you provided to us.

Comment: Putting a function declaration inside of another function declaration is a bad idea unless you assign it to a variable and use an anonymous function, which I think is rather useless since it doesn't make the function available for other uses.  In that case I personally would rather build the code right into the function and avoid all context switching issues. And if you declare them separately you are back to the same issues of undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite you code like this:

```
function findAndDisplayMaxCombination() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var targetAmount = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
    var values = sheet.getRange("G4:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
    var timeLimit = 600;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var maxCombination = findMaxCombination(targetAmount, values, startTime, timeLimit);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Authorization check passed. Updating the sheet...", "Status", 5);
    sheet.getRange("I4:I").clearContent();
    for (var i = 0; i < maxCombination.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange("I" + (i + 4)).setValue(maxCombination[i]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("An error occurred. Check the logs for details.", "Error", 5);
  }
}

function search(index, currentSum, currentCombination) {
  if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > timeLimit * 1000) {
    return;
  }
  if (currentSum === target) {
    if (currentCombination.length > result.length) {
      result = currentCombination.slice(); // Update result with the longer combination
    }
    return;
  }
  if (index === values.length) {
    return;
  }
  search(index + 1, currentSum, currentCombination); // Exclude the current value
  search(index + 1, currentSum + values[index], currentCombination.concat(values[index])); // Include the current value
}

function findMaxCombination(target, values, startTime, timeLimit) {
  var result = [];
 search(0, 0, []);
  return result;
}
```

And then rerun it and you start getting the error that startTime is undefined.   Presumably you can debug it from there.

Comment: You will find numerous  undefined errors now.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. I was lucky to get where I am with this. Used Google, ChatGPT, StackOverflow to get where I am so I unfortunately can't debug from even here. But I do appreciate your help with this. Maybe I can get it figured out. Was using this for work and now just doesn't work for anyone, so kind of sucks.

Comment: I've posted an updated code above. I think I'm making progress

Comment: I don't think so.  Read my comment above.

Comment: Did  you intend to make search recursive?